# Trying to write code to pull data from all files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying code to search all workbooks and if it finds what is being searched it copies and pastes the whole row to a listbox in a userform.

We order a lot of parts and we would like to search to see when the part was ordered last. this search will pull up that info.

The code below is giving me an error message and I can't figure out why. `OBJECT DOESN’T SUPPORT THIS PROPERTY OR METHOD` the part in bold is being highlighted when I run the code.

Could anyone help with this?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sPath As String
Dim sfile As String
Dim C As Range
sPath = "\\192.168.1.4\ET_Documents\Shared Documents\Inventory Transactions\TRANSACTIONS AS OF 11-3-2017\"
sfile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheet1
ListBox1 = 0
Do While sfile <> ""
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sfile)
    With ListBox1
        For Each C In wb2.Columns("b8:b15")          ' THIS IS THE HIGHLIGHTED LINE
                If C = TextBox1.Value Then
                    With C.EntireRow
                        ListBox1.AddItem
                    End With
                End If
        Next
    End With
wb2.Close False
sfile = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, your Object (`wb2`) doesn't have a method or property that matches the method/property you tried to use (`columns`).

`Columns` is a property of an Excel [work*sheet* class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-columns-property-excel), while you are trying to use it with a work*book*, which [doesn't have that property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_properties.aspx).

Comment: Guess i could get rid of .Columns and use ws instead  each workbook it looks in only has one sheet.

Comment: removed the .Columns and added .Range  i don't receive an error but i am not seeing  the listbox populate either...  it should populate the list box with the Cell value that has the textbox1.value

Comment: Replace `wb2.Columns("b8:b15")` with `wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("b8:b15")`

Comment: i replaced the columns with what you said and i don't receive errors anymore...  just not seeing any results in the listbox either..

Comment: Things to try: `Dim C As Range`, add both `C.Value` and `TextBox1.Value` to the watch list, and then carefully step through the code using F8. Most likely, the listbox isn't populated because the loop never enters the expected location, and you need to figure out why. I'll bet there's either a value or maybe datatype mismatch.